Generate Nix hash for Git revision in a proactive way
Other than failing a nix-build and looking for the expected hash in the build log, what is the best way to proactively compute the hash ahead of filling in the argument to fetchFromGitHub (and other similar “Git forge” fetchers)?
fetchFromGitHub {
  owner = "OWNER";
  repo = "REPO";
  rev = "REVISION";
  hash = "sha256-AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA="; # ← ?
};

Assuming we already have a trusted clone of the repository containing the same REVISION, and we don’t wish to trust the Git forge to serve the right snapshot at https://gitforge.example/OWNER/REPO/archive/REVISION.tar.gz.

I agree that this way can seem unorthodox, but a large part of why its done this way is because the implementation details of the narHash are still relatively obscure and no real tooling exists to check them outside of its context. Hell, even nix-universal-prefetch, which no longer exists, used to use a failing build to find the hash

Of course, one can dump the contents of the Git revision onto the filesystem and let the standard Nix utilities compute the hash for it:
tmpdir=$(mktemp -d)
git -C /path/to/trusted-clone.git archive REVISION | tar -C "$tmpdir" -x
nix hash path "$tmpdir"
rm -rf "$tmpdir"

(Substitute nix-hash --sri --type sha256 "$tmpdir" if the experimental feature nix-command is not enabled.)

There is a nix tool made especially for this purpose, called nix-prefetch-url. Its usage is very simple
$ nix-prefetch-url https://gitforge.example/OWNER/REPO/archive/REVISION.tar.gz
path is '/nix/store/...'
...
$ nix-prefetch-url --type md5 https://gitforge.example/OWNER/REPO/archive/REVISION.tar.gz # if you want to use another hash than sha256
path is '/nix/store/...'
...
$

Even though, in practice, I find that just filling in "" for every hash and letting the build process tell me what to fill in is even simpler, because I don't have to write down the url (which is sometimes a bit more than a copy-paste, when the url is an expression other than just a literal).

I think I knew about that one, but It would still need to trust the Git forge to serve the right snapshot, so it’s not the answer I was hoping for.

@Amir this tool can by used independently of the source of the git repository. If you trust something that you have locally more than a remote mirror of that repository, then just use nix-prefetch-url file:///path/to/trusted-clone
